# How to remove header and footer for the partial pages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

How can i remove the header and footer in the partial pages in asp.net mvc4. How can i recognize the partial page in visual studio. What are the changes i have to do in the site.css to remove the header and footer.
I hope you understand my question.

Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use partial views you don't need to make any specific modifications in your stylesheets. Instead of returning a view, just return a partial view:

```
return PartialView("ThePartialViewsName");
```

To create a partial view, just check the box marked "Create as partial view" in the Add View dialog.

Comment: Thank you but if i am using the return PartialView("ThePartialViewsName"); then the style pages in the content are not working to that particular page

Comment: @naidu526 Are you including the stylesheets in the partial view or in a view? I could provide more detail if you can let me know exactly what you're trying to do (i.e. return a partial view to update part of a page, etc)

Comment: I am returning the partial view from that particular controller

Comment: I am included the styles in the list.css and that css file i have included it in my partial view page. Then proper stylings are coming as early(before returning the partial view)